# Keras Early Stopping Fails with Multi-loss model

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have used Keras early stopping function successfully on several models, but if fails when I attempt to use it on a model with two outputs and a separate loss metric for each: *vae1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'out_1':self.vae_loss,'out_2':'mse'})*

The model fits and performs successfully when early stopping is not used. However, the code below yields the following: *ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8, 1) for Tensor u'x_2:0', which has shape '(10, 1)*':

> *early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)*
>
> *model.fit({'x_1':self.X_train, 'x_2':self.Y_train},{'out_1':self.X_train, 'out_2':self.Y_train},
>               shuffle=True,epochs=self.argsD['number_epoch'], batch_size=self.argsD['batch_size'], 
>               callbacks [model_checkpoint,early_stopping],validation_split=0.2,verbose=self.argsD['verbose_fit'])*

This leads to my questions:

1. Does Keras early stopping support a multi-part loss function?
2. If so, what changes are required in my code?

Thanks.

michetonu:

The error is thrown when I attempt to fit the model with the following method. Error message is below method code.

Thanks very much and let me know if you need more information.

> METHOD
>
> > def train_es(self):
> >             model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', monitor='loss', save_best_only=True)
> >             model = self.model_vae()
> >             model.summary()
> >             early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
> >             #model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
> >      model.fit({'x_1':self.X_train, 'x_2':self.Y_train},{'out_1':self.X_train, 'out_2':self.Y_train},
> >                 shuffle=True,epochs=self.argsD['number_epoch'], batch_size=self.argsD['batch_size'], 
> >                 callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stopping],validation_split=0.2,verbose=self.argsD['verbose_fit'])
>
> ERROR MESSAGE
>
> > File "/Volumes/WiltBUP/@Analysis-Stats/@NN_CategoricalVariables/@AV/VAE/vae_cat_class_combs_4_S1.py", line 275, in 
> >       main()
> >     ￼ File "/Volumes/WiltBUP/@Analysis-Stats/@NN_CategoricalVariables/@AV/VAE/vae_cat_class_combs_4_S1.py", line 271, in main
> >       submitCombs_2(dataPlus,combBase,evalNotice2, args,combKeys,combVals)
> >     ￼ File "/Volumes/WiltBUP/@Analysis-Stats/@NN_CategoricalVariables/@AV/VAE/vae_cat_class_combs_4_S1.py", line 244, in submitCombs_2
> >       p0,p1,p2= VAE.main(combBase, comb, data, args)
> >     ￼ File "/Volumes/WiltBUP/@Analysis-Stats/@NN_CategoricalVariables/@AV/VAE/vae_cat_class_HPOpt4.py", line 242, in main
> >       vae.train_es()
> >     ￼ File "/Volumes/WiltBUP/@Analysis-Stats/@NN_CategoricalVariables/@AV/VAE/vae_cat_class_HPOpt4.py", line 117, in train_es
> >       callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stopping],validation_split=0.2,verbose=self.argsD['verbose_fit'])
> >     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1498, in fit
> >       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
> >     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1152, in _fit_loop
> >       outs = f(ins_batch)
> >     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2229, in **call**
> >       feed_dict=feed_dict)
> >     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
> >       run_metadata_ptr)
> >     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 944, in _run
> >       % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8, 1) for Tensor u'x_2:0', which has shape '(10, 1)'

Comment: What (Keras) function throws this error? Can you copypaste the whole error message?

Comment: minimal reproduction code?